# Xamarin Forms showing cached Signing Identities

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

What drives the values found in the Manual Provisioning / Signing Identity dropdown?  The values I am seeing don't match what I am seeing in XCode.

Here is what I am seeing in Visual Studio...

[image]

It is showing every Apple account I have ever added to XCode on my Mac.

To try and fix this, I deleted every provisioning profile on my Mac, with...

[image]

You can see the 'ls' command shows no files in the Provisioning Profiles directory.

To verify, I disconnected/reconnected to the Mac from Visual Studio, and, as expected, the only Signing Identities that showed were the two 'Automatic' ones.  The rest of the list was removed.  Again, all good and expected.

I then deleted **all** the Apple accounts in XCode and added back only the one I am interested in right now.  Then I clicked the Download Manual Profiles button.

As expected, 2 provisioning profiles downloaded from this account.

[image]

However, in VS 2017 on the PC, the same Signing Identities returned as they were before.  I don't even have these accounts listed in XCode any longer, so these are cached values.  I am not sure at this point if they are being read from the Mac or the PC?

[image]

How do I get rid of these so the Apple account listed in XCode is the one that drives the Signing Identities in Visual Studio?  I am seeing the same behavior across Xamarin Forms projects, so I am thinking the issue is on the Mac side.

Comment: Are you sure these do not exist in your key chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What drives the values found in the Manual Provisioning / Signing Identity dropdown?

In my knowledge, Visual studio refers to the Keychains for getting the Provisioning profiles and Signing Identity.

> How do I get rid of these so the Apple account listed in XCode is the one that drives the Signing Identities in Visual Studio?

Well simply remove the key chains and you will be good to go.

Comment: Where are the keychains? How can I remove them?

Comment: @NimeCloud [Keychains](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/keychain-access/kyca1083/mac) are basically user identities that have account information. To find them in your mac open spotlight search and look for keychains, It will have all the keychains you have added in your machine. You remove them like you remove any other file else by right-clicking and deleting!

Comment: My bad; I got same problem on Windows VS 2019.

Answer (score 3):

These are sourced from the key chain.  I removed them from the key chain, and the list reset.